# Understanding Post Formats/Custom Post types Etc

Tags: custom-post-types, php, post-formats

I don't understand what "Adding Post Type Support" is for when we have "Adding Theme Support"?

For different post-formats this is the way I was shown before. This is then how I did it for the project I was working on, is this a correct/good way to do it?

here is whats in my `functions.php` file:

```
<?php add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array('image', 'video', 'gallery')); ?>
```

and here is what is in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
```

I also want to know if I should "custom post type" for what I describe below:

Lets say I have a page called "giftshop" with posts (also trying to figure that part out now) and I want to use the `image` format for each post but then I have a page that I'm only going to show one post called "newsletter" and I also want to use the `image` format but have it styled a little different, is that possible?

Comment: *"Also how do I make pages display posts."* - This is a different question entirely. Please post it as a separate question (but be sure to search the site for related questions first.)

Comment: *"Is it possible to have a "Supported Format" be used more than once"* - I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "use the supported format more than once". Are `giftshop` and `newsletter` custom post types?

Comment: There is no need to delete the content of this question, only to rewrite it in a new question. That's what question edits are for.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the [**Post Formats Codex entry**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats).

### Post Formats are a Taxonomy

Keep in mind that, under the hood, post formats are simply a *taxonomy* with a fancy UI and wrapper functions.

### `add_theme_support()`

The [**`add_theme_support( 'post-formats' )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) call tells WordPress that the current Theme supports the core Post Formats feature. Basically, it tells WordPress to expose the Post Formats meta box on the post-edit screen.

### List of supported post formats

Supported formats can only include the limited set of post formats (i.e. the set of `post_format` taxonomy *terms*) defined by core:

- aside
- gallery
- link
- image
- quote
- status
- video
- audio
- chat

### `get_template_part()`/`get_post_format()`

The `<?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>` call is used in the template to include a template-part file named `content-$format.php`, and will fallback to include `content.php` if the current post does not have a post format assigned.

### `add_post_type_support()`

> I don't understand what "Adding Post Type Support" is for when we have "Adding Theme Support"?

By default, post formats only apply to the `post` (i.e. *blog post*) post-type. You can use [**`add_post_type_support( $posttype, $feature )`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) to add support for that feature to the specified post-type. For example, to add post-format support to the `page` (i.e. *static page*) post-type:

```
add_theme_support( 'page', 'post-formats' );
```

### Targeting post formats via CSS

> Lets say I have a page called "giftshop" with posts (also trying to figure that part out now) and I want to use the image format for each post but then I have a page that I'm only going to show one post called "newsletter" and I also want to use the image format but have it styled a little different, is that possible?

This is entirely possible, via CSS.

First, be sure that your Theme uses both the [**`body_class()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and the [**`post_class()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) template tags.

Then, assuming you're using a custom page template, with a filename `template-giftshop.php`, you can target that page specifically via the **`body.page-template-template-giftshop-php`** CSS class.

Then, assuming you're targeting the `image` post-format, and your loop markup includes something like the following:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

...the `post_class()` template tag will add a `.format-$format` CSS class. So, you can target the `image` post format via **`.format-image`**.

Thus, you can target posts with the `image` post format specifically on pages that have the `template-giftshop.php` custom page template assigned like so:

```
body.page-template-template-giftshop-php .format-image {}
```

Likewise, you can target posts with the `image` post format specifically on pages that have the `template-newsletter.php` custom page template assigned like so:

```
body.page-template-template-newsletter-php .format-image {}
```

Comment: I added some comments to your question, related to your edits.

Comment: Where should I start now that we have the question figured out?

Comment: See **Targeting post formats via CSS**.